# Resouce ID of Dynamically added image by Picasso Android library

Tags: android, android-resources, picasso

I have a preGenerated Image URLs in a array.
And by Loop I am going to download and need to keep those images pass in another library.
I want to load every image in the same imageView 
        ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Picasso.with(this).load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5w9Z.jpg").into(imageView1);

and keep the resource ID in separate Array to pass( Like below in case of I have all images in drawable folder)
        private static int[] images = { R.drawable.nature_1, R.drawable.nature_2, R.drawable.nature_3, R.drawable.nature_4, R.drawable.nature_5 };

I am not sure the above approach but I want to get the resource ID of my dynamically loaded images.

So Please guide me.

Thanks.

--Ruhul

Answer (score 0):

`Resource ID` is to images that are within the `drawable` folders. Downloaded images will not have a `Resource ID`. You have to pass this images as `Bitmaps` or by using `Uri`

Comment: Ok. Understand. Thanks. Now Could you please tell me How I will get URI( I have URL).